# Tailwind CSS with React doesn't apply color to some Divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a login and a home page, they both share the same colors, but on the login form the color is not applied like it is on the home page.

Here is my `Login.jsx` page:

```
<div className="App">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
                <div className="px-8 py-6 mt-4 text-left bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg shadow-2xl bg-egloback1">
                    <h3 className="text-2xl text-white font-bold text-center">Login</h3>
                    {Status === false && (
                        <p className="text-center text-red-900 mt-3">{data.error}</p>
                    )}
                    <div className="mt-4">
                        <div>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email"
                                className="w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 focus:outline-0 caret-white text-white bg-egloinput1 border border-transparent rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-[#9441f2] duration-300" onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)} value={Email} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt-4">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"
                                className="w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 focus:outline-0 caret-white text-white bg-egloinput1 border border-transparent rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-[#9441f2] duration-300" onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)} value={Password} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex items-baseline justify-between">
                            <button className="px-6 py-2 mt-4 text-white bg-eglobutton1 rounded-lg hover:bg-eglobutton2 duration-300" onClick={Login}>Login</button>
                            <a href="/reset" className="text-sm text-blue-600 hover:underline">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is what it renders as:

[image: Photo of login page]

But on my `Home.jsx` page (which shares the same colors and files as the Login page) it looks like this (which is how it is supposed to look, the squares/rectangles are the correct color, and are what the login page box should look like):

[image: Photo of home page]

Here is my `Home.jsx` code:

```
<LoadingOverlay active={isActive} fadeSpeed={400} spinner styles={{
            spinner: (base) => ({ ...base, width: '30px', '& svg circle': { stroke: 'rgba(255,255,255,255)' } }),
            overlay: (base) => ({ ...base, background: 'rgba(17,17,17,1)' }), wrapper: { width: '100%', height: '100%' }
        }}>
            <div className="App">
                <Sidebar />
                <p className="select-none text-center mt-16 text-4xl underline decoration-1 underline-offset-8">Welcome, {data.name}</p>
                <p className="animate-pulse select-none font-mono text-center mt-3 text-sm">You have {data.notification_count} notifications</p>
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-[200px] mt-[80px]">
                    <div className="rounded-lg bg-egloback1 w-48 h-[120px] m-[5px]">
                        <p className="text-center mt-[49px]">No favourite 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="rounded-lg bg-egloback1 w-48 h-[120px] m-[5px]">
                        <p className="text-center mt-[49px]">No favourite 2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-[-70px] h-[200px]">
                    <div className="rounded-lg bg-egloback1 w-[395px] h-[120px] m-[5px]">
                        <p className="text-center mt-1">Announcements:</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </LoadingOverlay>
```

And for reference here is the `tailwind.config.cjs` file with the custom colors:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        egloback1: '#1e1e1e',
                eglobutton1: '#9441f2',
                eglobutton2: '#761fdb',
                egloinput1: '#303030'
      },
    },
    },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And for reference again here is my `App.css` file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

html {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #111111;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

p, s, i, b {
    color: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
body {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

@tailwind utilities;
```

I tried embedding the color codes directly instead of using the config file (like `bg-[#00000f]`, instead of `bg-egloback1`) which did not work, I tried restarting the development server and changing the import orders of my CSS file for the project, which also did not work.

Strangely enough, whenever I change the name of the color from `egloback1` to something different in both the config and app files, the color is correct for a few minutes, then it goes back to white.

SOLUTION:

I figured out the solution to this issue. It was an issue with the DIV not rendering everything properly? It seems to be a weird TailwindCSS bug, but I found a workaround:

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
<div className="px-8 py-6 mt-4 text-left bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg shadow-2xl bg-egloback1">
```

I replaced that code with:

```
<div className="flex flex-row min-h-screen justify-center items-center">
<div className="rounded-lg bg-egloback1 w-[290px] h-full p-7 m-[5px]">
```

Those both center the DIV in the middle of the screen, and I have not had any issues with the bottom one. Just an annoying TailwindCSS bug :p

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your entire code into a project and it seems to work perfectly fine. Can you try this?

Move these lines at the start of the index.css file from App.css.

```html
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Here is how Login.jsx code renders on my end.
[image]

Comment: I tried this, but after about an hour it will revert back. I found a solution though, It was an issue with the main DIV that was centering the box with the login stuff, apparently that was the issue. Thank you though.